# How can I fill individual parts of given circle?

Tags: math, raphael

How can I fill individual parts of given circle?

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);

function NGon(x, y, N, side, angle) {
    paper.circle(x, y, 3).attr("fill", "black");

    var path = [],
        c, temp_x, temp_y, theta;

    for (c = 0; c <= N; c += 1) {
        theta = (c + 0.5) / N * 2 * Math.PI;
        temp_x = x + Math.cos(theta) * side;
        temp_y = y + Math.sin(theta) * side;
        path.push(["M",x,y])
        path.push(["L",temp_x,temp_y])
    }
    return path;
}

paper.path(NGon(50, 50, 8, 20));
paper.circle(50,50,20)
```

Also [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LoohsjL6/).

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you need to do?

Comment: i want to fill individual part of circle not whole circle.http://jsfiddle.net/mnh6gg9h/

Comment: individual parts? do you mean chords, donuts or cheese triangles?

Comment: yes, individual parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the svg path line type A "elliptical Arc" with the same x and y radius.

You can fill as much individual parts as you like.

```
"A rX rY x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y"
```

give same radius for X and Y, keep the x-axis-rotation and the large-arc-flag as 0 and sweep-flag as 1, and very important the final point needs to be part of the imaginary complete circle. It will draw a perfect circle arc.

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/d0xL6590/

change the number of parts on the fiddle to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
circ = paper.circle(50,50,20);
poly = paper.path(NGon(50, 50, 5, 20));
circ.attr("fill", "#f00");
poly.attr("fill","#fff");
```

This has the effect of shading the part between the polygon and the circle.